# What is the correct way to implement the Discrete Fourier Transform for complex values in Python?

Tags: python, math, fft

I am starting to try some more interesting projects in python, which has led me to attempt to create a program that will take in a text file of x and y coordinates and produce an epicycle animation such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qgreAUpPwM&t=96s). I've already got a function that can draw an epicycle with a given centre, radius, frequency and phase. The way I've approached the 'maths' bit is by doing a discrete Fourier transform on a list of complex numbers(corresponding to the x-y coordinates). Here's my code for the DFT:

```
def dft(vals):
  transformed=[]
  N=len(vals)
  for k in range(0,N):
    coeff=0
    upper_freq=0

    if k>N/2 :
        b=-k
    else:
        b=k

    for n in range(0,N):

        coeff+=(vals[n]*(np.e**(-2*np.pi*1j*k*n*1/N)))
        
    transformed.append([coeff,b])

return transformed
```

This gives me a list of pairs of numbers, the first of which is the coefficient and the second the frequency.I then loop over this list to get the radius, phase and frequency of the corresponding epicycle like this :

```
for item in weights:
  complex_no=item[0]
  rad=abs(complex_no)*2/(len(weights))
  final_freq=item[1]/len(weights)
  phase=math.atan(complex_no.imag/complex_no.real)
  if final_freq != 0:
    rad_freq.append([rad,final_freq,phase])
```

This seems to work fine for coordinates of a square (created programatically), but when I try to use a more complicated path of coordinates, the cycler goes all wrong. Therefore, my question is whether the first code is the correct implementation of the DFT (I'm particularly unsure of dealing with which frequencies are negative), and whether this is the correct way to extract radius/phase/frequency information from the DFT-ed coordinates ?

[image: Square drawn properly with program]
Above:Square drawn properly with program
[image: Intended Path]
Above:Intended Path
[image: Actual Path]
Above:Actual Path

Many thanks in advance,
Chris

---

**UPDATE**
I have updated my DFT code :

```
`
def dft_1(vals):
    transformed=[]
    coeff=0
    N=len(vals)
    if N % 2==0:
        for k in range(int((-N/2) +1),int(N/2 +1)):
            coeff=0
            for n in range(0,N):
                coeff+=(vals[n]*(np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*k*n*1/N)))
            transformed.append([coeff,k])
    else:
        for k in range(int(-(N-1)/2),int((N-1)/2)):
            for n in range(0,N):
                coeff+=(vals[n]*(np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*k*n*1/N)))
            transformed.append([coeff,k])
    return transformed


`
```

However, this has made little difference to the code, so I am suspecting it is something to do with the rest of my drawing/animating code. I have created a GitHub project for this now so others can look at/ critique my code: https://github.com/FourierFoibles/Fourier-Pygame - I am extremely grateful to those who have already replied and those who help in the future.

Chris

Comment: Nice use of graphics.  Maybe you can start by seeing the answer you get with a library and then revisit your implementation: https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter24.02-Discrete-Fourier-Transform.html or this: https://hub.packtpub.com/compute-discrete-fourier-transform-dft-using-scipy/

Comment: @duffymo Thanks! I'll try this and try to get back and edit regarding this!

Comment: The right way is to use `numpy.fft` and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am trying to learn about the DFT through attempting implementation, and using NumPy would therefore not be a great help. Many thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Instead of `np.e**(…)` do `np.exp(..)`, which is likely more precise. And skip the inner loop in favor of array operations. But I don’t see an obvious problem with your DFT code. Are you sure the drawing code is correct?

Comment: @CrisLuego thanks for the exp suggestion - I've used it in my updated Dft code- I think you're right about the drawing and so I've put my code up on github for criticism. Still trying to get the hang of list comprehensions!